# Python YouTube Video Downloader

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, youtube

I'm looking for some feedback on my first 'real' Python program. Started with Python a few days ago and wanted to get right into it and make something hands on.

Currently the program lets you download audio and video for a YouTube video using Pytube. It allows you specify the location to save the download, whether to download Audio or Video and what resolution to download videos at.

```
#global variables
yt = None
res = None
stream = None
file_path = None
av_swtich = None


#see if the user wants to download audio or video

def av_select():
    global av_switch
    print('Would you like to download Video or Audio:')
    while True:
        av_switch = input('Please enter \'1\' for Video and \'2\' for Audio\n')
        if av_switch not in ('1', '2'):
            print('Pleae make a valid selection')
            continue
        else:
            break

#Download Audio Stream

def audio_download():
    global yt
    global file_path
    print('The Video has the following audio streams')
    print(*yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True), sep='\n')
    while True:
        itag = input('Please Enter the Itag of the stream you want to download:\n')
        try:
            yt.streams.get_by_itag(str(itag)).download(output_path=str(file_path), filename_prefix='Audio-')
            print('The audio stream has been downloaded')
            return True
        except:
            print('You have entered an invalid Itag')
            continue
        
#Define Download location 
def download_location():
    global file_path
    while True:
        file_path = input('Please enter the Folder to save the Video in:\n')
        x = os.path.exists(path = str(file_path))
        if x == True:
            break
        else:
            print('The specified Folder does not exit')
            continue

#Select the video that the user wants to use
def video_select():
    global yt
    while True:
        video = input('Please enter the video URL:\n')
        try:
            yt = YouTube(video)
            print('The title of the video you selected is: ' + yt.title)
            return False
        except:
            print('The URL is not Valid\n')
            continue

#Select resoultion and display possible stings
def resoultion_select():
    global res
    global res_list
    while True:
        res = input('Please enter a Resoultion:\n')
        try:
            res_list = yt.streams.filter(resolution= str(res))
            return False
        except:
            print('You have entered an invalid resoultion')
            continue

#Select the stream to download based on the itag
def download_stream():
    global file_path
    global yt
    global res_list
    print('The Video has the following streams')
    print(*res_list, sep='\n')
    while True:
        itag = input('Please Enter the Itag of the stream you want to download:\n')
        try:
            yt.streams.get_by_itag(str(itag)).download(str(file_path))
            print('The video has been downloaded')
            return True
        except:
            print('You have entered an invalid Itag')
            continue


def Main():
    global av_switch
    print('Welcome to the Youtube Video Downloader\n')
    download_location()
    video_select()
    av_select()
    if av_switch == '1':
        resoultion_select()
        download_stream()
    else:
        audio_download()
    
Main()
```

Comment: "_using Pytube_" nowhere in the code I see pytube being imported. please provide a complete program.

Comment: it is seen that on function download_stream(), the line "yt.streams.get_by_itag(str(itag)).download(str(file_path))"  downloads the stream into "file_path" . 'hope it helps

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Global variables

- one major suggestion - don't (over)use global variables, it's generally not a good practice and it will make more difficult to test the code. For example if you'd like to add a functionality for downloading multiple items at the same time you'll have a hard time with it.

So instead of this:

```
def av_select():
    global av_switch # this function is setting value for this variable


def Main():
    global av_switch # this function is reading this variable
    av_select()
```

do this:

```
def av_select():
    while True:
        av_switch = input('Please enter \'1\' for Video and \'2\' for Audio\n')
        if av_switch not in ('1', '2'):
            print('Please make a valid selection')
            continue
        return av_switch # add return statement with the value


def Main():
    av_switch = av_select() # use the value returned from function
    if av_switch == '1':
```

same applies to other global variables.

### Python coding guidelines

- follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines, in this case the name of the function `Main` is violating it - function names should be lowercase.
- recommended way how to do code comments is to use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Instead of this:

```
#Define Download location 
def download_location():
```

do this:

```
def download_location():
   """define download location"""
```

this way the comment can be accessed as `download_location.__doc__` and a lot of tools (eg. for generating documentation) can work with it.

### Code flow

- the following one is probably a matter of taste, but it feels like you're overusing `while True:` loops in places where you can rely on other variables you are "waiting" for. For example `av_select()` - I'd use the `aw_switch` variable as a condition of the loop this way:

```
def av_select():
    av_switch = None
    while av_switch not in ('1', '2'):
        av_switch = input('Please enter \'1\' for Video and \'2\' for Audio\n')

    # outside the while loop, av_switch finally matches '1' or '2'
    return av_switch
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these imports at first and 2nd line of the code:

```
import os
from pytube import YouTube
```

Also, the full path of the destination folder needs to be entered when code asks 'Please enter the Folder to save the Video in'.